# How can print \t in console?

Tags: python-3.x

In python console:

```
>>> x="\t"
>>> x
'\t'
>>> print(x)
    
>>>
```

How can make print(x)  output `\t`?

Comment: please set ｘas "\\t"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a raw string to avoid escaping the backslash like in Avad’s answer:

```py
x = r"\t"
print(x)
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-raw-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is a tabulator sign but if you want to print value `"\t"` you have to escape it two times:

```
x = "\\t hello"
y = "\t hello"
print(x)
print(y)
```

**Output**

```
"\t hello"
"     hello"
```